# Trying to match numbers but getting hung up on matching floating numbers

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

So at work I use excel for lots of different use cases. Recently, I've had to do some math on certain excel docs that came in to my email, so I figured why not automate it. The idea is to scan certain columns, add them up, and if they are past a certain number, divide by 1000. I'm able to do it for a few, but now I'm stuck at floating integers.

```
#! python3

import pandas as pd
import re

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Test_doc.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1', usecols=['CPUs'])
df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet2', usecols=['Memory'])
df3 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet3', usecols=['Storage'])



cpu = int(df.sum())         # example 75
memory = int(df2.sum())     # example 175616  
storage = float(df3.sum())  # example 37449601.714689255

def conversion(text):
    if 4 >= len(str(text)):
        print("number")
    elif 5 >= len(str(text)):
        print("Ten Thousand")
        text = text / 1000
        print(text)    
    elif 6 >= len(str(text)):
        print("Hundred")
        text = text / 1000
        print(text) 
    elif 7 >= len(str(text)):
        print("Million")
        text = text / 1000
        print(text) 
    elif 8 >= len(str(text)):
        print("Ten Million")
        text = text / 1000 / 1000
        print(str(text))
    else:
        print("Not here")


conversion(storage)
```

When I execute through conversion(), I get "Not Here". I've tried it a few times with different numbers greater than 00000000 and get the same result.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your `conversion` function?

Comment: Why are you doing `4 >= len(str(text))` ? This will test whether the string representation of `text` has at least 4 characters or not. That's not how number comparisons should be done. For example, this method will consider the period in `10.1` to be a digit give you 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is a number (you'd better pick a less misleading name), so you can just compare that number to other numbers:

```
def conversion(text):
    if text < 10_000:
        print(text)
    elif text < 100_000_000:
        text /= 1000
        print(text)
    else:
        print("Not here")
```

This works for float and integer numbers.